Google Cloud VM Stops Responding During Build Process with "googleapis" Package
I am encountering a critical issue with my Google Cloud VM instance when using the googleapis npm package in my NestJS project. The problem arises specifically when I run the npm run build command to build the application. The instance becomes completely unresponsive, requiring a manual restart to regain functionality.
Environment

System memory: 4GB

Architecture: x86/64

Node.js Version: 20.18.1

npm Version: 10.9.1

Package Manager: npm

Framework: NestJS

Relevant Dependency: googleapis (v144.0.0)


Issue Behavior:

After adding googleapis to the project and running npm run build, the build process starts as expected.

Midway through the build, the instance becomes entirely unresponsive.

The VM requires a manual reboot to restore connectivity.

No specific error logs are available since the instance stops responding entirely.


import { BadRequestException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
// import { join } from 'path';
// import { google, sheets_v4 } from 'googleapis';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleSheetsService {
  // private sheets: sheets_v4.Sheets;

  constructor() {
    // const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    //   keyFile: join(__dirname, '../../config', 'credentials.json'),
    //   scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
    // });
    //
    // this.sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
  }
}

When I comment import, the project is successfully being built.
I must mention, that I haven’t any issue on local. The project is being built, and running.

The issue is not clear, Please add more details. Also mention what debugging steps have you tried. Version of googleapis package, Machine Specs and steps to reproduce the issue.

@atef-hares, I have provided the whole details. When I am running project building script (nest build or npm run build) on my local environment project  is successfully being built, but on google cloud the instance becomes entirely unresponsive.

Since your build appears to start normally, becomes unresponsive midway through the process and restarting the instance restores connectivity, there is most likely a resource exhaustion issue that happens during the build. Try increasing the size of the disk attached to your instance and increasing the allocated RAM and the number of vCPUs you are using.
